# on Python, given a word for example "peter" and any emoji for example "" how can I get this result

Tags: python

on Python, given a word for example "peter" and any emoji for example ""
how can I get this result

```
`word = "Peter"
emoji = ""

# Print the word with doubled letters followed by the emoji
print(''.join([l * 2 for l in word]) + emoji)

# Loop through the positions of the emoji and construct two strings for each position
for i in range(1, len(word) * 2, 2):
    first = ''.join([word[j] * 2 for j in range(i//2+1)])
    second = ''.join([word[j] * 2 for j in range(i//2+1, len(word))])
    print(first + emoji + second)
    print(first + second + emoji)

# Print the emoji followed by the reversed word with doubled letters, without the last two characters
print(emoji + ''.join([l * 2 for l in word[::-1][2:]]))`
```

I am not having this

[image]

Comment: Do you need spaces between the letters?  Your code would probably be simpler if you just used one emoji, had a loop to put it into place, and then had a function to print the string with letters doubled and a space in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I described.  I convert the string to a list so I can use `insert` to insert the emoji into place.  You could do this with string operations if you want.

```
word = "Peter"
emoji = ""

# Print with doubled letters.
def double(s):
    o = [l*2 for l in s]
    return ' '.join(o)

for i in range(len(word),-1,-1):
    wordl = list(word)
    wordl.insert(i,emoji)
    print(double(wordl))
```

Output:

```
PP ee tt ee rr 
PP ee tt ee  rr
PP ee tt  ee rr
PP ee  tt ee rr
PP  ee tt ee rr
 PP ee tt ee rr
```